# Dynamic Language Translator

Tags: android

How to translate the text from English to Hindi at run time (Dynamic data) in Android App without using Google Translate API. I am able to translate the static data by using different String files for different languages, but to translate the Dynamic Data which comes from server , I need a solution. I don't want to use Google Translate API.

Comment: you will have to create your owntranslation engine with a database of at least all words' translations. Prepare to spend up to 10 years on that.

Comment: By Exploring I got this International Components for Unicode (ICU) libraries, but not much to use ICU in App.Please suggest ,if any one have any idea.